# How can one properly handle Nginx routing with a dynamic ending?

Tags: nginx, proxy

More specifically, I have the static files of a React application in an Nginx container, and I want to serve those files at the route `http://localhost/rooms/:id`. The ID, is just an integer, and that integer determines the API call that the browser will make to the backend. I am having trouble telling Nginx to ignore the ID, and just serve the static files.

Here is my Nginx config file:

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript;
    
    server {
        listen 80;

        location /rooms/ {
            root /var/www/rooms;
            index index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
            root /var/www/rooms;
            expires 30d;
        }
    }
}


events { }
```

How can I tell Nginx to ignore everything after `/rooms/`?

The end result I would like is:

1. http://localhost/rooms/1 serves the static files in root
2. http://localhost/rooms/2 serves the same static files in root

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you use different route for your api call, but if you really want to use it like this, just add the index file to try files. and you should also use root outside location block.

```
  root /var/www/rooms;
  location /rooms/ {
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html /index.html =404;
    }
```